# javascript passing values to the function not working

Tags: javascript

I had asked this question yesterday but my code was not clear so couldnt get an answer, i have tried to create a replica of actual problem here.

what i am trying to do is thre is a html table, i am iterating for all rows then to a ***particular column of every rows*** i am attaching an event handler which on being clicked should output some computed object, but it always return  `{"isTrusted":true}`

```
 var ff = function(el){
    return function(el){ alert(el) }; // the output is always {"isTrusted":true}
 }

function Fi(selector, func) {
         document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(function(node{
          node.onclick = func;
          })
       ;}

//-------------- main calling code--------------------------------

 document.querySelectorAll('#myTable > tbody > tr').forEach(function (node) {

    cells = node.querySelectorAll('td');
    var info = {};
    info.age = cells[1].innerText;
    Fi('td:nth-child(1) > a', ff(info));

})
```

EDIT:

i tried doing this:

```
var ff = function (el) {
   return function() { alert(el) };
}
```

BUt the problem is 
for every row of table there should be an new info object created which is infact happening ,

```
document.querySelectorAll('#myTable > tbody > tr').forEach(function (node) {

    cells = node.querySelectorAll('td');

  //--------->loop over all rows and create info object

    var info = {};
    info.age = cells[1].innerText;

   //---------> when the cell is clicked always the last info object is shown but for every row it should be different

    Fi('td:nth-child(1) > a', ff(info));

})
```

Comment: ` document.querySelectorAll.(` That's not valid.

Comment: You have an extra `.` after `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it was typo while typing here .fixed it but thats not theisuue

Comment: `querySelectorAll` only takes 1 argument. If you want to search inside `node`, use `node.querySelectorAll('td');`.

Comment: And the second argument to `Fi` should be `function() { ff(info); }`.

Comment: And `Fi` will search for the first match of the selector in the whole document, not the current row of the table.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  var ff = function(el){
>     return function(el){ alert(el) }; // the output is always {"isTrusted":true}
>  }
> ```

`ff` takes a parameter `el`. It then returns a function which *also* takes a parameter `el`. That latter `el` shadows the former `el`. So `el` will be the argument which is passed to the event handler directly, not the one passed to `ff` (and that'll be an `Event` object).

Get rid of the inner `el` parameter:

```
var ff = function (el) {
   return function () { alert(el) };
}
```

Comment: i used the version you gave initially but in that case info object was always the last value that wsa ebing generated was

Comment: Not sure I get what you're saying.

Comment: @anekix `Fi('td:nth-child(1) > a', ff(info));` is a generic selector, so it will always add an event handler to all `a` elements with latest info value.

Comment: @anekix gvmani already pointed out the problem above. You're just attaching the event handler to all `td:nth-child(1)`. To all *global* `td:nth-child(1)` anywhere in your document!

Comment: @gvmani why the latest `info` value? this is eaxctly what is happening and i dont want this behaviour. to avoid this i created `ff()` function

Comment: @anekix Because you do `node.onclick = func`. You replacing the `onclick` handler, and only the last one will stick.

Comment: @anekix Be more selective about what element you attach the `onclick` handler to, I suppose. Also use `addEventListener()` instead of overwriting `onclick`.